# Faculty job application - search committee chair, dept head, and follow up emails

Tags: application, job-search, faculty-application, interview

I recently interviewed for a tenure track position in a public R1 University. There were 4 candidates. The last one interviewed at the beginning of April. Two weeks ago, I have been told by the chair of the search committee that they have submitted the summary to the dept head and now the choice is in her hand. Currently, I am still waiting.

The emails from the chair and the dept head have always been very matter-of-fact and straight-to-the-point. Particularly, when I sent thank you emails to all the people I met during the interview, the chair is one of the few who did not reply back (overall reply rate ~75%). Does it mean anything? Should I be worried about it? Or am I overthinking? Did you have a similar experience to mine but got the offer anyway?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks for all of your responses. I did not get the position. Therefore, I still think the "vibe" matters. I assume that if I was their top candidate, our interaction would have been more positive.

Comment: Let me paraphrase this answer. 'Under the assumption that my model is correct the data show that my model is correct'. I hope you can see the circularity of your argument!

Answer (score 3):

Probably overthinking. The chair has other duties, of course. And, since they have the responsibility to make a decision, they might find it improper to communicate outside the committee.

Let it go. You will learn soon enough.

Answer (score 3):

You're overthinking it. All parties involved are required to be neutral between all candidates, and so can't say much that would actually mean anything to you. You'll just have to wait and see.